# Using np.where as an interval boundary

Tags: python, numpy

If I use the following code:

```
def edge_rollover(data, phi_width, phi_height, phi_width_fine, phi_height_fine):
    length = int(np.size(data) // 2)
    step_width_limit = 0.001    


    limit = [0, 0]
    k = length - 1
    
    interval_start = int(np.where(data[:, 0] == 0.1)[0])
    
    print(interval_start)
    
    for i in range(k, interval_start, -1):
        x_1 = data[i, 0]
        x_2 = data[np.where(data[:,0]-data[0,0] == data[i,0]-0.1), 0]
        y_1 = data[i, 1]
        y_2 = data[np.where(data[:,1]-data[0,1] == data[i,1]-0.1), 1]
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Which I dont understand. The np.where method should only return the index of the value 0.1. So why can I not turn it into an integer or if thats not the problem then why can I not use it as a boundary for the interval?

Comment: Note that `where` returns the values in the array that satisfy the condition not their indexes. You should try [`argwhere`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) instead.

Comment: Which `where` is giving the error?  Get in the habit of showing the full error message.  @MattPitkin, `np.where` does not return values.  It returns a tuple of index arrays.  `argwhere` just applies `transpose` to that, creating a 2d array that's better for iterative indexing

Comment: I'm going to guess it's `int(np.where(data[:, 0] == 0.1)[0])` (the other `where` uses are wrong in a different way).  Look at that `where` result without the index or the `int`.  As the error says, `int` only works if the argument is represents ONE number,   If `where` finds none, or more than 1, you'll get this error.

Comment: `==0.1` equality tests on floats are not reliable.  `np.isclose` is better.